# AWS s3.listobjects doesn't respond with latest info on cordova APP

Tags: xcode, cordova, amazon-web-services, sapui5

I am using javascript based AWS APIs to upload and display documents.
This is within a SAPUI5 application, which all works fine in a desktop browser.

Now using cordova we generated a IOS application, in here we could successfully upload a document to AWS, but then when I call s3.listobjects I don't get the updated list as response (say initially I have 3 images in a folder, then I upload a new one and call listobjects again but I still get only 3 files from response). as the same time I check the app from desktop version it does display latest list.

here is my code for instance.

```
/*
    getAWSAttachments:function(vController, folder) {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
     Bucket: vController.folder, /* required */
     Prefix:faultId,
     EncodingType: 'url'
    };
    s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
     console.log(err, err.stack);
     } else{
     console.log(data);
     }
    });
},
s3.putObject(params2, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {

        console.log("Error uUploading the file", err);
    } else {
        vController.getAWSAttachment(vController, vController.faultId);
    }
});
//before calling the above methods I config AWS as below in inti of the view
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("awsmodel").oData.AccessKey,
    secretAccessKey: this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("awsmodel").oData.SecretKey,
    signatureCache:true,
    sslEnabled:true,
    correctClockSkew:true,
    httpOptions:{xhrAsync:false}
});

*/
```

Not sure if the cordova app with in app browser casing any issue or is there a cache parameter causing this.

Before posting this, I have gone though cordova AWS plugin but as I see the example it uses the same methods so not sure if thats going to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As found out this is due to the NSURL Cache being held in iOS device.
We added the corresponding Cordova plugin and cleared the chache. This sorted out the issue.

I don't have the code handy with me, but if you need it please do reply me to this post, I will dig it up by then.

Cheers,
Sai